# FPDF html table to display data from mysql

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm new to fpdf and I'm having trouble on how  can I display the data based on my input field. In myh input field php file I will put the name,date etc and I have a print button where when I clicked It will automatically print what I inputted in that field. Now I want that to be printed in a table form format. Below is the fpdf file:

```
<?php

$html = <<<MYTABLE

<table border="1" style="width:90%" title="Leave" cellpadding="5px" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=1 width="70"   align:"top-left"><center><b>1. Name:</b></center><br><select name="office_agency"></td>
        <td rowspan=1 width="100"  colspan="2" align:"top-left"><b>2. ID&nbsp;&nbsp; / &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Date</b><br> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ......
    </tr>
</table>

MYTABLE;
require('pdftable.inc.php');

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('auth');

$p = new PDFTable();
$p->AddPage();
$p->setfont('times','',10);
$p->Cell(5,-5,'APPLICATION FOR LEAVE');
$p->Ln(3);
$p->htmltable($html);
$p->output();
?>
```

There. how can put the code for fetching the inputted data following the html format or is there any way than this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you cannot use the html table for direct display,you can create the table using the col() syntax for more check this link [here]
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php